# How to investigate the times a library function like rand() is invoked in C

Tags: random

Is there a way to find how many times the C library function rand() has been called during an execution of a program? The program is written by myself thus its code can be edited.

I can find how many times rand() is called using Visual Studio debugger. However, I found that my program produces different random number sequence when running outside the debugger. Thus I want to investigate the invocation times outside the debugger as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce the same set of random number just set the seed value to a predetermined value:

```
int main()
{
    srand(0); // The random number sequence should now be deterministic.
    // STUFF
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works. That means different seeds are used inside and outside the debugger. Thanks.